# Clarification on Proof from Folland's Analysis - Sobolev Embedding Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces

This is Theorem 8.54, the Sobolev Embedding Theorem, in Folland's Analysis: If $s>k + (n/d)$, then $H_s \subset C_0^k$. (Here $H_s$ is defined to be the Sobolev space and $C_0^k = \big\{f \in C^k(\mathbb{R}^n:\partial^\alpha f \in C_0 \text{ for } |\alpha | \leq k\big\}$).

Proof: Suppose $f \in H_s$; by the Fourier inversion theorem and the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma, it will suffice to show that $\widehat{\partial^\alpha f} \in L^1$ for $|\alpha| \leq k$.

He then goes on to prove this. However, why does it suffice to show that $\widehat{\partial^\alpha f} \in L^1$?

Reference: I am using the following copy of Folland found online: [here](http://www.ru.ac.bd/stat/wp-content/uploads/sites/25/2019/03/406_04_Folland_Real_Analysis_Modern_TechniquesF.pdf)

Comment: If $\hat{g} \in L^1$, then $g$ is continuous and goes to zero at infinity. In this case $g = \widehat{\partial^\alpha f}$.

Comment: @user90189 Could you please go through the argument using Riemann-Lebesgue and Fourier inversion that shows this? That is where I’m struggling.

Comment: @slowspider I think you misunderstood user90189's idea. Let me say more about it. If $\hat g\in L^1$, then use Fourier inversion theorem and Riemann-Lebesgue lemma:  Theorem 8.22(f), we can show that $g\in C_0$. Now apply this result to $g=\partial^\alpha f$ for $|\alpha|\leq k$. We know that $\partial^\alpha f\in C_0$ for all $|\alpha|\leq k$, so $f\in C_0^k$.

Comment: More details: Let $h(\xi)=\hat g(-\xi)$, then by Fourier inversion theoem, $g=\hat h$. Since $h\in L^1$, using Riemann-Lebesge lemma gives that $g=\hat h\in C_0$.